# JQuery Mobile: Dynamically changing data-type='horizontal' to data-type='vertical'

Tags: jquery, mobile

#### Problem

I have a JQuery Mobile site and I'm trying to dynamically change the attribute of a     fieldset from `data-type='horizontal'` to `data-type='vertical'`. I can get the DOM to change but I can't get JQM to refresh the view of the DOM in the browser after the change has been made.

I've seen a lot of examples for refreshing list and radiobutton attributes but not fieldset attributes.

#### Code

```
if(e.orientation == "portrait"){
    //In portrait mode, all radio buttons should be vertical.
    $('fieldset').attr('data-type', 'vertical').controlgroup('refresh');
}
else{
    //In landscape mode, all radio buttons should be horizontal.
    $('fieldset').attr('data-type', 'horizontal').controlgroup('refresh');
}
//trigger the page to recreate itself.
$('#newentry').trigger('create');
```

#### Conclusion

I've tried:

```
checkboxradio('refresh')
```

and this gives me:

```
cannot call methods on checkboxradio prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'.
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

calling `checkboxradio();`
instead of `checkboxradio('refresh');`
might initialize it for you, not really sure without seeing more code